# Merge 3 SQL Queries, whats the right join?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a couple queries i would like to merge into 1 query and am not sure what the right join would be.

This query gets all the arcs that match the pid:

```
var arcs = db.Query("SELECT arc FROM comics WHERE `publisher`=" + pid + " GROUP BY arc").ToList();
```

This query gets the title of the arc from the arcs table:

```
var ar = db.QuerySingle("SELECT title FROM arcs WHERE id=" + arc.arc);
```

This Query is used to get the total issues that match arc.arc and pid:

```
var issues = db.Query("SELECT id FROM comics WHERE arc=" + arc.arc + " AND publisher=" + pid);
```

The Whole Code:

```
@{
    var pid = Request["pid"];

    var db = Database.Open("quickly");
    var publisher = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM publishers WHERE id=@0",  pid);

    Page.Title = publisher.name + " @";

    var arcs = db.Query("SELECT arc FROM comics WHERE `publisher`=" + pid + " GROUP BY arc").ToList();
}

<div class="post">
    <div class="post-bgtop">
        <div class="post-bgbtm">
            <h2 class="title">@publisher.name</h2>
            <div class="entry">
                <p>
                    <table width="100%" border="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th align="left">Title</th>
                                <th>Issues</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>  
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach (var arc in arcs) {
                                var ar = db.QuerySingle("SELECT title FROM arcs WHERE id=" + arc.arc);
                                var issues = db.Query("SELECT id FROM comics WHERE arc=" + arc.arc + " AND publisher=" + pid);
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="@Href("~/Comics/Arcs?aid=" + arc.arc)">@ar.title</a></td>
                                <td align="center">@issues.Count</td>
                            </tr>
                            }
                        </tbody>     
                    </table>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `arcs` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `plot` longtext NOT NULL,
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `title` (`title`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comics` (
  `id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `arc` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `issue` decimal(5,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `plot` longtext NOT NULL,
  `publisher` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `published` date NOT NULL,
  `cover` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT './images/nopic.jpg',
  `added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `views` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `owned` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `arc` (`arc`,`title`,`issue`,`publisher`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `publishers` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `plot` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to give us more information about tables structure.

My first approach is something like this..

```
Select 
cs.arc as 'Arc', 
arcs.title as 'Arc_Title', 
id as 'Issues'
from 
Comics cs 
left join Arcs arcs on cs.arc = arcs.id
left join Comics cs2 on cs.arc = cs2.arc and publisher = @pid
```

but I don't really know since I am guessing about tables structre

**Edit...**

I understand that one arc could be in more than one comic. And that you need different arcs and how many times they repeat.
So I think this would work:

```
Select 
t1.arc as 'Arc_ID', 
t1.title as 'Arc_Title', 
count(t1.arc) as 'issues'
from (
Select c.id, c.arc, a.title
    from comics c
    left join arcs a on c.arc = a.id
    where c.publisher = 1) as t1
group by t1.arc, t1.title
```

Here is an example.. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9fda/8/0

Comment: oops sorry bout that, i'll add it in now.